# Elliptic functions: Weierstrass psi function limit

Tags: limits, periodic-functions, elliptic-functions

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

Show that
$\lim_{z \to 0} z^2( \psi(z)-\psi(\frac{w_j}{2})) =1$

where $\psi(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum\limits_{w \in \Omega}' \frac{1}{(z-w)^2}-\frac{1}{w^2}$

where $\Omega$ are the periods of $\psi(z)$

2. Relevant equations
3. The attempt at a solution

$\lim_{z \to 0} z^2( \psi(z)-\psi(\frac{w_j}{2}))= 1 + \sum\limits_{w\in \Omega}'\frac{z^2}{(z-w)^2}-\frac{z^2}{w^2}$

The last time clearly vanishes.

For the second term I can write this as $\frac{1}{(1-\frac{w}{z})^2} \to 1 $ as $z \to 0 $

So I get

$\lim_{z \to 0} z^2( \psi(z)-\psi(\frac{w_j}{2})) =1+ \sum_{w \in \Omega}' 1$

This is probably a stupid question but I don't really understand the summation second term here.

$\sum_{n=1}^{n=n} 1 = n$ right?

So there's an infintie number of $ w \in \Omega $ so obviously I dont want to do this, are you in affect looking at the limit '$mod \Omega $', so where the first term corresponds to $w=0 $ ?

Many thanks

Comment: This function is normally written as $\wp$ (`\wp`).

Comment: Assuming $\wp$ is meant, the limit of $z^2 \wp(z)=1$ is true.

Comment: For a lattice $\Lambda = \alpha (\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})$ : $\displaystyle\wp(z)- \frac{1}{z^2}=\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda \setminus 0} \frac{z (2 \lambda-z)}{(z-\lambda^2)\lambda^2}$
You need to show it converges uniformly (to an analytic function) for $|z|$ small enough